# How can i execute commands inside containers during host provision

Tags: linux, docker, vagrant, containers

I am using vagrant to build docker host and then i have shell script which basically install all required packages for host and  That script also build and run containers

vagrant file

```
config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "sudo /vagrant/bootstrap.sh"
```

Inside that i run containers like

```
docker run -d  . .bla bla .. .
```

This works fine  but i have to ssh into container and run `make deploy` to install all the stuff.

Is there any way i can run that `make deploy` from within my `bootsrap.sh`.

The one way is make that as entry point but then that will do with every run,

I just want that when i provision host then that command should run inside some container and show me output like vagarnt shows for host

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `docker exec`

see the doc

http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/exec/

for example

`docker exec -it container_id make deploy`

or

`docker exec -it container_id bash`

and then

`make deploy`

inside your container

Comment: my makefile is in /var/www dir , how can i execute that

Comment: something like `cd /var/www ; make deploy` you get the idea

Comment: Thanks , so u mean i can even run multiple commands on one line

Comment: yes, or you can have a script that does the cd and the make, and you launch it, see for example the last 2 `docker exec`at https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/k3ck3c/captvty/

Comment: You could also simplify them into the single command: `make -C /var/www deploy`